# How to replace Match value with other value in Regex

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex, asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0

I have string `string testString = "Test id=10 sgdsdg id=15"`
I want to replace 10 by 100 and 15 by 150
I wrote

```
string testString = "Test id=10 sgdsdg id=15";

Regex testregex = new Regex("(?<=id=)\\d+");

MatchCollection matchCollection = testregex.Matches(testString);

foreach (Match match in matchCollection)
{
    if (match.Value.Equals("10"))
    {
        match.Result("100");
    }

    if (match.Value.Equals("15"))
    {
        match.Result("150");
    }
}
```

I don't want to use following, as for every match I have to check some case. like id 
`Match.Value =10 Match.Value =12`

```
testregex .Replace(testString , m => oldNewValueMapping[m.Value])
```

Comment: `Regex.Replace(yourString, @"(?<=id=)(\d+)", "$10");`

Comment: but it will replace both 10 and 15 by same $10, what you consider here $10 as?

Comment: The `$1` will refer to the first group in your regular expression, which for the first match, will return `10`. The regex engine will attempt to match the string once again, and it will, the second time returning `15`, which will be once again stored within `$1`. The problem is that doing `$10` will instruct the regex engine to check for the 10th matched group, which does not exist. I've proposed a work around to this below.

Comment: can you please write the entire code. i tried it, but its not working.

Answer (score 1):

There is a minor problem with replacing with `$10` since the .NET engine will look for the 10th group.

To go around this, simply use *named* groups instead, like so:

```
string testString = "Test id=10 sgdsdg id=15";
Console.WriteLine(Regex.Replace(testString, @"(?<=id=)(?<digit>\d+)", "${digit}0"));
```

Yields:

```
Test id=100 sgdsdg id=150
```

Please refer to [this](http://www.regular-expressions.info/named.html) link for more information on name groups.

Comment: 100 and 150 is just a example. I want to do lots of check. that's why i want to use switch case.

Comment: @HemantMalpote: As long as that pattern applies: `id=<somedigit(s)>`, then the expression will still hold.

Comment: I think you are getting what i want. I have to perform lots of operation for different different match in match collection.